# Drools API not updating value as expected

Tags: drools, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

MyProblem: Based on TrainData I want to set the value of TrainStatus via postman call but I am not getting expected response.

How i can achieve this ?

I have created two data objects-

**TrainData**-

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| trainID | integer |
| area | String |

**TrainStatus**-

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| TrainStatus | String |
| DriverName | String |

**Drl file**-

```
rule "set Train status"

when
    TDobj : TrainData(trainID==111 && area=="South")
    TSobj : TrainStatus()
then
    TSobj.setTrainStatus("running");
end
```

**Request:**

- Endpoint: http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/demo_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

```
{ 
     "lookup": null,
     "commands": [ 
                {"insert": { "object":{ "TrainData":{  "trainID":112 , "area":"South"}},
               
                "out-identifier": "TrainData", 
                "return-object":true
                } }, 

                {"insert": { "object":{ "TrainStatus":{ }},
               
                "out-identifier": "TrainStatus", 
                "return-object":true
                } }, 

                { "fire-all-rules": {}}                              
        ] 
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "type": "SUCCESS",
    "msg": "Container demo_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT successfully called.",
    "result": {
        "execution-results": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "com.dummyspace.demo.TrainData": {
                            "trainID": 112,
                            "area": "South",
                            "trainType": null
                        }
                    },
                    "key": "TrainData"
                },
                {
                    "value": {
                        "com.dummyspace.demo.TrainStatus": {
                            "trainStatus": "Running",
                            "auditInterval": null,
                            "hpbufferAllowance": null
                        }
                    },
                    "key": "TrainStatus"
                }
            ],
            "facts": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle": {
                            "external-form": "0:5:2011994629:2011994629:5:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.dummyspace.demo.TrainData"
                        }
                    },
                    "key": "TrainData"
                },
                {
                    "value": {
                        "org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle": {
                            "external-form": "0:6:1902014052:1902014052:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.dummyspace.demo.TrainStatus"
                        }
                    },
                    "key": "TrainStatus"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My rule is if TrainData==111 and area=="south" then set TrainStatus to "Running".
but in body if I am entering different train data/area irrespective of condition I am getting TrainStatus = Running.

I am not getting response based on the condition.

Comment: `i am not getting expected response` -- well what _are_ you getting? And what are you sending as your request? Also I hope those curly quotes/"smart" quotes in your DRL are just copy-paste artifacts and not actually in your code.

Comment: Also you have what looks like a typo in your "then": `TSobj:setTrainStatus(“running”);` should be `TSobj.setTrainStatus("running");` (`.` not `:`). I'm presuming this is a typo since the rule as written won't even compile.

Comment: I have edited my question and added API Body and Response

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the actual DRL? as mentioned in previous comment the current looks like some kind of copy-paste error and won't even compile.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to remove ( : ) from  TSobj.setTrainStatus("running");

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you are reporting that allegedly the TrainStatus is not correctly valorized.

In your description, you say:

> My rule is if TrainData==111 and area=="south" then set TrainStatus to "Running". but in body if I am entering different train data/area irrespective of condition I am getting TrainStatus = Running.

In your snippet response, you have:

```
"trainStatus": "Running",
```

but on request to provide the actual DRL file, you provide:

```
rule "set Train status"

when
    TDobj : TrainData(trainID==111 && area=="South")
    TSobj : TrainStatus()
then
    TSobj.setTrainStatus("running");
end
```

which clearly is A. not the actual DRL, B. not the only rule in the rule base, since the setter is valorizing with `"running"` (lowercase R) which is inconsistent from the alleged reported issue/question.

Based on the information provided, it's difficult to investigate further, and just by the current available information I would suspect there is something else going on based on this inconsistency; consider providing a full reproducer (e.g. the KJAR project shared on github for example).